# How do I complete the Gnome Character Map with missing Unicode characters?

Tags: language-support, special-characters

I often use the Gnome Character Map accessory to find characters I didn't know, with a view to surprising friends with exclusive drawings. However the program is not complete and lacks some characters like the Mongol or the Birman ones.

How do I install all of them in one time? Notice that I don't care what precise font it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please note that the Unicode character range is *immense*; **There is no one font that covers all of it** (although GNU FreeFont comes pretty close).

If you see empty spaces, or even empty pages, it may be because they just [haven't been assigned yet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29). Those will remain empty until [the Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html) utilises them. Even though there is space for 1,114,111 glyphs, but only specific ranges have characters assigned to them, and between those ranges, there may be **quite a bit of unused room**.

You can get great coverage with the following fonts; Between them, they cover as much of Unicode as is practically usable:

- [Linux Libertine](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ttf-linux-libertine) (my favourite, [→ project site](http://linuxlibertine.sourceforge.net/))
- [Droid](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ttf-droid) (includes droid-fallback for cjk support)
- [WenQuanYi Zen Hei](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ttf-wqy-zenhei) (focus on Chinese)
- [GNU Freefont](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/otf-freefont) (best coverage of any free-as-in-freedom font)

(click these links to install the fonts on your Ubuntu system)

[image]
<sub>(source: [fontscape.com](http://www.fontscape.com/pictures/sourceforge/LinuxLibertine.gif))</sub>

*Linux Libertine is one that, on top
 of covering a massive span of Unicode,
 looks excellent and has fantastic
 kerning and hinting.*

Also, if you don't mind a *non free* font, there is [Code2000, Code2001 and Code2002](http://www.code2000.net/), which, between them, cover quite a substantial chunk of the Unicode range (97% I think) as well.

For a list of Unicode fonts and their coverage, see [[image] Unicode Typeface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_typeface#List_of_Unicode_fonts).

Answer (score 3):

The program seems complete (at least, it lists the Mongolian script/codepage).  But I don't have a font installed that includes those glyphs, maybe that's what you mean?  You might have to find a font that includes these.

I think the `ttf-unifont` package contains most glyphs, but not necessarily beautiful ones, and they don't show up correctly in scripts where letters look different depending on their location inside a word etc.

If you want better quality glyphs, it might be a good idea to install a specialized font for that script and/or language, e.g. `ttf-manchufont` for Mongolian, or `ttf-sil-padauk` for languages from Myanmar/Burma.

Comment: I am interested in beautiful glyphs, but in fact for every script that exists in the Gnome Character Map. Could you explain how to search for them or give a link to download them all?

Comment: My recommendation is not to use any of the multi-script fonts if you want beautiful & correct glyphs, but search script by script for the best font(s).  Designing a **good** font is really, really difficult, and for somebody who's not familiar with a script in daily use it's even more difficult.