# How can unicode symbols u+2404 ␄ EOT and u+2405 ␅ ENQ be corrected?

Tags: 12.04, unicode, unicode-entry

The title above is rendered incorrectly in Ubuntu 12.04 as:

[image: switched glyphs]

The unicode title identifications are correct for the codes but the symbols are switched. EOT ␄ is the same as control-D but unfortunately the wrong symbol is used. (likewise ENQ ␅ control-E)

#### References:

[[image: AU Favicon]  AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com):

- [How do I complete the Gnome Character Map with missing Unicode characters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13133/how-do-i-complete-the-gnome-character-map-with-missing-unicode-characters)
- [Found an error in font in Ubuntu, where and how should I report it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59784/found-an-error-in-font-in-ubuntu-where-and-how-should-i-report-it)
  Escalation info not pursued. Is there a more immediate solution?
- [How can I configure default fonts by unicode blocks or single codepoints?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33716/how-can-i-configure-default-fonts-by-unicode-blocks-or-single-codepoints)
  An answer to this question would provide some remedial info.

#### [Curios[image: Wikipedia Favicon]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curio)  - interesting asides:

[[image: SU Favicon]  SuperUser](http://superuser.com):

- [Producing a specific ASCII character in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/196673/producing-a-specific-ascii-character-in-ubuntu)

  [[image: AU Favicon]  AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com):
- [How can I type ASCII characters like Alt + numpad in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88347/how-can-i-type-ascii-characters-like-altnumpad-in-windows)
- [Ways to enter special characters? Is Alt+Numpad possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23330/ways-to-enter-special-characters-is-altnumpad-possible)
- [Alt + ASCII code like in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172293/alt-ascii-code-like-in-windows)
- [What feature is at play when Ctrl+Shift+Alt+U,E "types" an unprintable hex 000E?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12426/what-feature-is-at-play-when-ctrlshftaltu-e-types-an-unprintable-hex-000e)
  Note: The glyph code `u+240E` ␎ (which also is wrong!) is used when referring to `u+000E` aka SO (Shift Out) or control-N, basically any control code is rendered as a symbol by adding 2400<sub>hex</sub> to the control code to get the equivalent Unicode glyph.
- [How can I type accentuated characters like ë?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358/how-can-i-type-special-characters-like-e)

  [[image: Wikipedia Favicon]   Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org):
- [Wikipedia Article on Shift Out and Shift In "characters"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_Out_and_Shift_In_characters)
- [Wikipedia control code chart showing associated glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart)
  Compare the chart's ENQuiry ENQ, End Of Transmission EOT and Shift Out SO character symbols on a machine which renders them correctly (ie. NOT a stock Ubuntu 12.04 OS machine), with `u+2404`, `u+2405` & `u+240E` in `character map` (run it from the utility icon or use a terminal command: `gucharmap` or `gnome-character-map`).

#### Enquiry symbol

[image: Enquiry symbol]

#### End of Transmission symbol

[image: End of Transmission symbol]

#### Also the u+240e glyph is wrong for Shift Out, SO, ^N, u+000e

[image]

Can these be easily fixed?

Comment: Jai: TQ for edit to show images to compare with  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart

Comment: @georgerowell Please make sure you're logged in with the same user account you used when you posted the question. This will also make it so your edits are applied immediately, rather than having to go through a review process. If you want to get your user accounts merged, [follow the guidelines given here](http://askubuntu.com/help)

Comment: Report it as a bug on the Ubuntu Font.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in more recent versions of Ubuntu, and was reported in this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-freefont/+bug/1070669

I doubt it's severe enough to be considered for a "Stable Release Update", so you'll probably just have to live with it until you can upgrade: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates